# Filtering items using a condition (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**This is now solved**

**The problem**

I am trying to make a filter that does this. 
Gets 'name' from session storage and matches it with 'name' on product.

I'm storing all 'logged in' user data on 'sessionStorage' for practice. 
I'm storing all the 'products' in 'localStorage'

I'm just doing this as a small project to understand and practice vue & js.

Basically if the product has been created by user x, upon login, user x should only be able to see the products he listed and not the rest of the products.
 
**This is what I can do**

I can get the user info from sessionStorage and when creating a product, the user 'name' is passed on along with the product details. 

I can also retrieve all the products from localStorage.

I don't know how to come up with a filter using vue.js that does this.

Some code sample would really help me understand whats going on.

Additionally, I want to display the results in html.

Thanks in advance.

````
    },
    computed: {
        filteredProducts() {
            this.products.filter(x => x.name === this.loggedUser[0].user);
        }
    },

});```



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7PMf.png
````

Comment: Are you also retrieving the products from sessionStorage? I would assume that the products is stored and retrieved from a database via an API. If that is the case, then you should design your API so that when the user calls the method to get the products, you can pass a parameter (the user login id) so that the products being returned are only those products that belong to the logged in user.

Comment: Hi Angelo, no, I am just getting 'products' from localStorage.
Just doing this as a practice.

Comment: If you have the Vue Dev Tools in your Chrome browser, you can inspect the value of the computed property for `filteredProducts` with the codes provided below as an answer and see if that matches what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
computed: {
  filteredProducts() {
    return this.products.filter(x => x.name === this.loggedUser[0].text); // text or user, whichever field is for username
  },
},
```

After that show the list in html use `v-for`.

```
<p v-if="filteredProducts.length === 0">No products found</p>
<li v-for="(product, key) in filteredProducts" :key="key">Product: {{ product.description }}, Price {{ product.price }} <button @click="deleteProduct(key)">Delete</button></li>
```

add delete method

```
methods: {
 // ...
 deleteProduct(index) {
        this.products.splice(index, 1);
 },
}
```

Comment: This results in undefined, even if i use -this.loggedUser[0].user. Products do show in the array (vue dev tools) and the user is present in loggedUser[0]

Comment: if you add products `addProduct ()`, is it showing in list. u should at least get anempty array in products not `undefined`.

Comment: If I add products it shows them perfectly fine. I can even v-for on html and display them all. addProduct() does work. I've made a few changes, I've updated this post with the full code.

Comment: @Calv just add return keyword

Comment: now it shows "filteredProducts:Array[0]", how do i test on html to see if it is displaying only the filtered products?

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you! What if I want to edit, delete them? Sorry for the questions.

Comment: for edit use `v-model` and add a function similar to delete method

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work from you (given what you have provided above)

```
computed: {
  filteredProducts () {
    return this.products.filter(function (item) {
      return (item.name === this.loggedUser[0].name)
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, we are filtering the products based on the name that is tagged on that list with the `loggedUser` name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong. But when I paste your code in, it keeps showing ' , ' expected. The code by prisar goes through but vue dev tools shows 'undefined' which is odd as the 'products' array does show all the products in it.

Comment: Fixed that, but now it just shows 'error during evaluation.'